# Como fazer uma consulta utilizando variaveis com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou tentando fazer a seguinte consulta no banco através do PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM nwpedidos WHERE `nomeUsuario` = 'Nome'
```

Porém, o 'Nome' varia de acordo com quem faz a consulta, pra isso passo uma variavel via javascript. O problema é que a consulta não retorna nada se eu utilizar variavel como no exemplo abaixo, mas se eu usar o comando completo como no exemplo acima, tudo funciona normalmente.

```
<script>
 var a = getName();
 function getName(){
    var b = document.getElementById("LoginName1").innerText;
    var res = b.split(":");
    return res[1].trim();
 }
 </script>
<?php
require_once("connect.php"); //conectar no banco
$var = "<script>document.write(a);</script>"; //pegar o conteudo da variavel JS
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `nwpedidos` WHERE `nomeUsuario` = '" . $var . "'"; //consulta no banco (que não retorna nada)
$resultado = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);
while ($dado = $resultado->fetch_object()) {
?>
```

Comment: cara da um var_dump($var); e ve posta aqui o resultado acredito que a informação dentro do $var que está incorreta por isso não retorna nada!

Comment: Por que não salvar o nome do usuário na sessão?

Comment: o var_dump ja havia testado, a principio está certo. 'string(35)'

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus com cookies por exemplo?

Comment: @GabrielSarates usando Sessions, como você pega o nome do usuário e salva em `var a`?

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus com o javascript, o usuário está escrito num span com o ID LoginName1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo com recarregamento da página.

Vamos supor que você está no arquivo index.php ok.

1°) Arquivo index.php parte (html), criação do botão (Atualizar)

```html
<input type="button" id="submitUser" value="Atualizar" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

2º) Arquivo index.php parte (js)

```js
//Criando obj user
user = new Object();

//Aaproveitando sua função...
//Função para obter o nome do usuário logado
function getName(){
    var b = document.getElementById("LoginName1").innerText;
    var res = b.split(":");
    return res[1].trim();
}

//Espera meio segundo para garantir o carregamento... DOM
setTimeout(() => {
    //Atribuindo o nome do usuário
    user.name = getName();

    //Cria url para o mesmo arquivo (index.php) passando parâmetro usuario_name
    var url = "location.href='index.php?user_name="+user.name;    
    
    //Localiza o botão que vai submeter
    var submitUser = document.getElementById('submitUser');

    //Adiciona ao botão o url passando o usuário na ação do click
    submitUser.setAttribute("onclick", url)    
}, 500);
```

3°) Arquivo index.php parte (php)

```js
<?php
/*Recebendo o user_name pela url com ($_GET)
Só faz a consulta se existir o user_name na url.*/
if (isset($_GET['user_name']))
{   
    /*Atribuindo o usuário recebido por ($_GET) a váriavel ($userName)*/
    $userName = $_GET['user_name'];

    /*Conectar no banco*/
    require_once("connect.php");

    /*Consulta no banco*/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nwpedidos WHERE nomeUsuario = '$userName' "; 
    $resultado = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    while ($dado = $resultado->fetch_object()) {
} else {
    /*Caso o usuário não seja passado na url, criar um alert*/
    echo "<script>alert('Erro: Usuário não detectado.');</script>"
}
?>
```

Se quiser sem recarregar a pagina, podes usar Ajax...

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, não sei como você está obtendo o valor de `LoginName1`.

Mas suponho que você tenha este valor em algum lugar da sua página (Seja via session ou banco de dados)

E por usar `innerText`, talvez esteja em algum elemento de texto, `<label>, <span>`, etc..

Da forma que está fazendo, a variável `$var`, está vazia.

Reproduzi então o seu exemplo, para que você tenha uma noção de como passar um valor para a variável `$var`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste Query</title>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="#"> 
        <label>Login Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="login-nome-input" value="usuario:gustavo">
    <button type="button" id="btn-pesquisar"  >Pesquisar</button>
    <p>

    <span id="login-nome">usuario:frederico</span>
           <br>      
  
    <br>
    <label id="resultado"></label>
    </form>     
</body>

<script> 
var nome = getName();
 
function getName(){
   var b = document.getElementById('login-nome').innerText;  
   var res = b.split(':');
   var texto = 'RESULTADO DA QUERY: '
   return texto + res[1].trim();
}
 
function getNameInput(){
   var b = document.getElementById('login-nome-input').value;  
   var res = b.split(":");
   return res[1].trim();  
}
 
 $('#btn-pesquisar').click(function() {
   var r = getNameInput();
   $('#resultado').text(r);
 });
</script>

<?php
   $var = "<script>document.writeln(nome);</script>";
   echo $var;
   require_once("connect.php"); //conectar no banco
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `nwpedidos` WHERE `nomeUsuario` = '" . $var . "'";
   // continua o codigo

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Wagner, tentei do seu método mas a consulta não retorna nada. Usei 'echo $sql' pra ver como ficou a consulta e apareceu um espaço depois da variavel, tentei usar um trim na variavel $var mas mesmo assim o espaço continua.  troquei o writeln por apenas write na $var e o espaço sumiu, mas mesmo assim a consulta não retorna nada

Comment: Se puder enviar um código mais completo, vai ajudar, só para eu saber como voce está recebendo o valor LoginName1; atualize a questão com mais detalhes

Comment: O LoginName1 é um span. Mas consegui resolver o problema usando Session mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: @GabrielSarates, valeeuu..
Se minha resposta foi útil em alguma coisa, aceite-a por favor!! T+